# Using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Ninject 2 from scratch

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ninject-2

I just did File -> New Project last night on a new project. Ah, the 
smell of green fields.

I am using the just released ASP.NET MVC 2 (i.e. no preview or release 
candidate, the real thing), and thought I'd get off to a good start 
using Ninject 2 (also released version) with the MVC extensions. I 
downloaded the MVC extensions project, opened it in VS2008Sp1, built 
it in release mode, and then went into the mvc2\build\release folder 
and copied Ninject.dll and Ninject.Web.Mvc.dll from there to the 
Libraries folder on my project (so that I can lug them around in 
source control and always have the right version everywhere). I didn't 
include the corresponding .xml files - should I? Do they just provide 
intellisense, or some other function? Not a big deal I believe.

Anyhoo, I followed the most up-to-date advice I could find; I 
referenced the DLLs in my MVC2 project, then went to work on 
Global.asax.cs. First I made it inherit from NinjectHttpApplication. I 
removed the Application_Start() method, and overrode OnApplicationStarted() instead. Here is that method:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted() 
{ 
    base.OnApplicationStarted(); 
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
    // RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
}
```

And I also followed the advice of VS and implemented the CreateKernel 
method:

```
protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel() 
{ 
    // RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
    return new StandardKernel(); 
}
```

That is all. No other modifications to the project.

You'll notice that the RegisterAllControllersIn() method is commented 
out in two places above. I've figured I can run it in three different 
combinations, all with their funky side effects;

- Running it like above.

I am then presented with the standard "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC" page in 
all its' glory. However, after this page is displayed correctly in the 
browser, VS shows me an exception that was thrown. It throws in 
NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(), which was called 
with a NULL value in the controllerType parameter. Notice that this 
happens after the /Home page is rendered - I have no idea why it is 
called again, and by using breakpoints I've already determined that 
GetControllerInstance() has been successfully called for the 
HomeController. Why this new call with controllerType as null? I 
really have no idea. Pressing F5 at this time takes me back to the 
browser, no complaints there.

- Uncommenting the RegisterAllControllersIn() method in 
  CreateKernel()

This is where stuff is really starting to get funky. Now I get a 404 
error. Some times I have also gotten an ArgumentNullException on the 
RegisterAllControllersIn() line, but that is pretty rare, and I have 
not been able to reproduce it.

- Uncommenting the RegisterAllControllers() method in 
  OnApplicationStarted()

(And putting the comment back on the one in CreateKernel())

Results in behavior that seems exactly like that in point 1.

So to keep from going on forever - is there an exact step-by-step 
guide on how to set up an MVC 2 project with Ninject 2 (both non-beta 
release versions) to get the controllers provided by Ninject? Of 
course I will then start providing some actual stuff for injection 
(like ISession objects and repositories, loggers etc), but I thought 
I'd get this working first.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

(Also posted to the Ninject Google Group)

Comment: This is in the process of being fixed by the Ninject guys. More when I have my head wrapped around it all!

Comment: Why are you not registering any modules like in http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc (readme.markdown) ? (I've seen the thread at http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/c011f0bd83993a59 ) ?

Comment: Hi,

The reason there are no modules is that this is a virgin project, and repositories and other stuff that will be injected doesn't exist yet. The first thing I did after setting up the MVC project was basically to add Ninject 2 to the mix, to make sure controller injection worked, and it didn't. So that's my reason. :)

Comment: +1 for the **Ah, the smell of green fields.** Especially when they start to blossom. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel dirty answering my own question, but for the benefit of anyone who might wander into this...

This is not a Ninject problem, really, it seems to be an issue with Cassini (the web server built into VS2k8), which handles these requests differently than IIS would handle them. The basic reason is that the app gets a request for favicon.ico, which Cassini sends to MVC, and Ninject didn't know how to handle it.

Ian Davis had a bug fix for this out in an impressively short amount of time, and also recommended to add an ignore route to avoid this problem specifically while doing development. Just add the following to your route config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Hope this helps someone!